# EGit - pull= failled and no conflicts

Tags: eclipse, git, svn, github, egit

When i do Team -> Pull on my project

I have result Failed, then below merge input i have tow modification but none of them is impacting the same file, so there is no conflicts.

Why is this showing as failed? Is this a bug?

[image: egit bug]

Comment: What version of EGit are you using?

Comment: One of the last one i guess i just installed it 2 months ago ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just did a Team -> Reset.

I choose "Mixed" (head and index) and looks like it's working.

(But i don't know if it's the best way)